# Parse xml in c#.net

Tags: c#, xml

I have to parse following xml in C#

```
<Packages>
      <Package>
         <PackageName>Create_Staging_Table</PackageName>
         <SequenceID>1</SequenceID>
         <AlwaysRun>True</AlwaysRun>
      </Package>
        <Package>
         <PackageName>Indigo_Staging_Load</PackageName>
         <SequenceID>2</SequenceID>
         <AlwaysRun>True</AlwaysRun>
      </Package>
        <Package>
         <PackageName>Indiogo_Load_Package</PackageName>
         <SequenceID>3</SequenceID>
         <AlwaysRun>True</AlwaysRun>
      </Package>
   </Packages>
```

I have tried

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
             doc.Load(filePath);
             XmlNode PackagesListNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Packages");
             XmlNodeList Packages = PackagesListNode.SelectNodes("Package");
             foreach (XmlNode node in Packages)
             {
                 TableLoadInstruction instruction = new TableLoadInstruction();
                 instruction.PackageName = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("PackageName").Value;
                 instruction.Sequence = Convert.ToInt16(node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("SequenceID").Value);
                 instruction.AlwaysRun = Convert.ToBoolean(node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("AlwaysRun").Value);
                 loadInstructions.Add(instruction);
             }
```

I have got error like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("PackageName").value since node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("PackageName") is 'null'

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You should include what **you have tried** and what **specific problem** you encountered.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials about this.

Comment: And the problem is....?

Comment: Many, many questions about extracting data from XML have already been asked and answered here.

Comment: OK, sou you have tried something. What went wrong? (Actual vs expected outcome, full error messages etc).

Comment: Henk I have got error like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("PackageName").value since node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("PackageName") is 'null'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got solution

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
             doc.Load(filePath);
             XmlNode PackagesListNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Packages");
             XmlNodeList Packages = PackagesListNode.SelectNodes("Package");
             foreach (XmlNode node in Packages)
             {
                 TableLoadInstruction instruction = new TableLoadInstruction();
                 instruction.PackageName = node.SelectSingleNode("PackageName").InnerText;
                 instruction.Sequence = Convert.ToInt16(node.SelectSingleNode("SequenceID").InnerText);
                 instruction.AlwaysRun = Convert.ToBoolean(node.SelectSingleNode("AlwaysRun").InnerText);
                 loadInstructions.Add(instruction);
             }
```

Comment: Just a hint: look into XDocument et al. Much shorter and easier.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do won't work because PackageName isn't an attribute. You have to look into the children nodes of Package.

Comment: You should provide this kind of responses as comment rather than as answer

Comment: But Zebra does not have the points to comment, and it is a partial answer. To an incomplete question.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for PackageName, that's anode into node.Attributes, so I think you'll never get a value for this xml. Is that your problem?